# How to swiftly hide on-screen keyboard with a gesture?

Tags: keyboard, 7.1-nougat, gestures

I'm using an ageing Nexus 6 with stock and rooted Android 7.1.1. The problem I have with most multi-featured keyboards is that they don't hide timely with my pace of app usage. So, with animations disabled, when I swiftly switch to an app and the keyboard was opened in last used app, it would not hide out with a breeze. Often I find a gap of one or more seconds which is irritating and unproductive.

Using Back key doesn't really work in such cases. I tried Hackers Keyboard while looking for a lightweight keyboard and while it provides a swipe action to hide keyboard (which reduces the severity of the issue here) I have productivity issues with the low and rigid width of its space bar which I have discussed [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/51105/14045). Furthermore, it lacks predictions which is another disappointment.

Ideally, I would prefer to use my Gboard or any alternative but *competitive* app but the competitive ones I tried, such as TouchPal, Swiftkey, Google Indic, suffers from performance issues on my device. As such, I'm looking for a way to hide any keyboard with a gesture and swiftly.

I tried to look for Xposed modules but to no avail. I also looked into GMD Gesture Control to my utter disappointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install [Xposed edge](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.jozein.xedge) module (see the help and support section on basics of how to use this module)
- In preferences *gesture on soft keyboard* is enabled by default. Disable that (optional)
- Choose an edge and the desired trigger (single tap, double tap etc from the 6 options) and action as soft keyboard → hide soft keyboard